# Fold swagger verb properties

Tags: folding, filetype-json

I have to edit regularly swagger JSON files to add a `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` property, files looks like:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "",
    "title": ""
  },
  "paths": {
    "/login": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Login",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "password"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid `name`"
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
            "uri": "${service-github}",
            "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
            "httpMethod": "POST",
            "type": "aws_proxy"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Empty": {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title" : "Empty Schema",
        "type" : "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like that `summary`, `parameters`, `responses`, and `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` to be folded for the whole file.

Comment: `"summary"` is a single line, so it can't be folded by itself... Do you mean fold the four others individually? Or fold the whole `"post"` block that contains them?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble actually, it does nothing.

Comment: @filbranden I mean, I want that all the children of a verb (`post` here), be on one line (folded or not), in order to quickly see if my key is missing.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble actually you are right, I had an old configuration interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to fold the lines, you can do

```
:setlocal foldmethod=syntax foldenable
```

and then open/close as desired (`:help folds`).

In the comments, you mention putting a whole block on one line. There's an easy way to do that, too:

```
:global/"key":/normal! V%J
```

(e.g., with `key` as `post`).

What we are doing is `J`oining all the lines from the start of the block to the end by `V`isually selecting the lines between braces (`%`). This assumes the brace is on the same line as the key, which is usually the case with formatted JSON. (If the JSON is not formatted, `:%!jq` or `:%!python -m json.tool` will format the whole file.)

If you really want to check for missing keys, though, might I suggest writing a program? Python's `json` module can load JSON as `dict`s; there's also `jq` and `gron` for the command line. Almost every practical programming language supports JSON.

Here's a simple Python function to tell you which keys are missing from a JSON-like object; you can load a JSON file using `json.load`:

```python
def missing_keys(obj, required_keys):
    return required_keys - obj.keys()
```

Some examples:

```python
>>> obj = json.load(...)
>>> missing_keys(obj['paths']['/login']['post'], {})
set()
>>> missing_keys(obj['paths']['/login']['post'], {'responses'})
set()
>>> missing_keys(obj['paths']['/login']['post'], {'responses', 'my-bad-key'})
{'my-bad-key'}
```

Here's the equivalent with `jq`:

```bash
$ <... jq '["responses"] - (.paths."/login".post | keys)'
[]
$ <... jq '["responses", "my-bad-key"] - (.paths."/login".post | keys)'
["my-bad-key"]
```

Here's a version that outputs true/false if all required keys are there:

```bash
$ <... jq '(["responses"] - (.paths."/login".post | keys) | length) == 0'
true
$ <... jq '(["responses", "my-bad-key"] - (.paths."/login".post | keys) | length) == 0'
false
```

And lastly a version that is silent (except possibly stderr) and produces an error code, so can be used in a script's `if`:

```bash
$ <... jq 'if (["responses"] - (.paths."/login".post | keys) | length) == 0 then halt else halt_error(1) end'
$ echo $?
0
$ <... jq 'if (["responses", "my-bad-key"] - (.paths."/login".post | keys) | length) == 0 then halt else halt_error(1) end'
{"openapi":"3.0.0","info":{"version":"","title":""},"paths":{"/login":{"post":{"summary":"Login","parameters":[{"required":false,"schema":{"type":"string"},"in":"query","name":"name"},{"required":false,"schema":{"type":"string"},"in":"query","name":"password"}],"responses":{"400":{"description":"Invalid `name`"}},"x-amazon-apigateway-integration":{"uri":"${service-github}","passthroughBehavior":"when_no_match","httpMethod":"POST","type":"aws_proxy"}}}},"components":{"schemas":{"Empty":{"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","title":"Empty Schema","type":"object"}}}}
$ echo $?
1
```